# How to get the ip-address of your peer using the same application as yours

Tags: java, p2p

I am developing a pure P2P application in java where one can broadcast,search,download a file with security...now i want to know whether there is some method to know the ip address of a peer in the network using the same application.

Comment: More details is needed. What Programming language, etc

Comment: This is too short for a correct question. Tell us more about the language you want to use?

Comment: working in java @BriceFavre

Comment: On a LAN, it's simple: you broadcast your existence.On the greater Internet, routers block broadcast and multicast traffic, so there's no way to announce your presence. Instead, we  need at least one peer as a seed, to discover the others. As each peer learns of others, it exchanges its knowledge with them.the question is how do we get that ip address of that one seed.?we are using WIFI as the medium @BriceFavre

Comment: You might be interested in [JXTA](https://jxse.kenai.com/).